# Distributed tensorflow source code

Tags: github, tensorflow, distributed-computing, distributed

I wanted to check the source code of the distributed training feature of tensorflow and its overall structure. Worker-PS relations, etc. However I am lost in tensorflow's repository. Can someone guide me through the repository and point the source code I am looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, not all tensorflow code (especially the part related to distributed computation) is open source. To quote Aurélien Géron from [Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn and TensorFlow](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920052289.do):

> The TensorFlow [whitepaper](http://download.tensorflow.org/paper/whitepaper2015.pdf) presents a friendly dynamic placer algorithm that auto-magically distributes operations across all available devices, taking into account things like the measured computation time in previous runs of the graph, estimations of the size of the input and output tensors to each operation, the amount of RAM available in each device, communication delay when transferring data in and out of devices, hints and constraints from the user, and more. Unfortunately, this sophisticated algorithm is internal to Google; it **was not released** in the open source version of TensorFlow.

But here are the main entry points of [TF distributed](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/docs_src/deploy/distributed.md) in the public repo:

- `Cluster` in [`tensorflow/python/grappler/cluster.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/grappler/cluster.py)
- `Server` and `ClusterSpec` in [`tensorflow/python/training/server_lib.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/server_lib.py)
- `worker_service.proto` in [`tensorflow/core/protobuf/worker_service.proto`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/protobuf/worker_service.proto)

To dive deep you'll need to enter native C++ code in [`tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime) package, e.g., here's [gRPC server implementation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_tensorflow_server.cc).

Comment: Wow. That is a bit shocking to me, who had thought that tensorflow is totally open-source. Great to know now. Thanks!

Comment: To be more precise, there are *two tensorflows*: one used internally in Google and one on GitHub. The engineers are trying to sync both. The version you're running on your computer *is* open source, but it's not the same as one that runs in Google

Comment: I see... but I can run distributed training in my computer, which is internal to Google. So I am a bit confused now.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Distributed training on your computer is open source and the links above describe what is actually running (and you can find worker/ps communication details there, other basic questions). But it is not the same as distributed training described in the paper and several posts on the web (e.g. on async gradients). This code is not on GitHub, so you can't find answers to *these* questions by looking at GitHub code. Hope it's more clear now.